Cannot Export HuggingFace Model to ONNX with Optimum-CLI
Summary
I am trying to export the CIDAS/clipseg-rd16 model to ONNX using optimum-cli as given in the HuggingFace documentation. However, I get an error saying

ValueError: Unrecognized configuration classes ('AutoModelForImageSegmentation', 'AutoModelForSemanticSegmentation') do not match with the model type clipseg and task image-segmentation.

Setup
Environment



Spec
Value




OS
Linux


OS Version
Ubuntu 22.04


Python
3.10.12


Python package manager
Poetry



Files
pyproject.toml
[tool.poetry]
name = "hello-clipseg"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = []
readme = "README.md"

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.10"
numpy = "^2.0.0"
matplotlib = "^3.9.0"
transformers = "^4.41.2"
optimum = {extras = ["exporters"], version = "^1.20.0"}


[build-system]
requires = ["poetry-core"]
build-backend = "poetry.core.masonry.api"


Error
$ optimum-cli export onnx --model CIDAS/clipseg-rd16 ./models/clipsed-rd16

Framework not specified. Using pt to export the model.
/home/macaw/sattwik/hello_clipseg/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py:1132: FutureWarning: `resume_download` is deprecated and will be removed in version 1.0.0. Downloads always resume when possible. If you want to force a new download, use `force_download=True`.
  warnings.warn(
config.json: 100%|██████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 4.73k/4.73k [00:00<00:00, 18.0MB/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/macaw/sattwik/hello_clipseg/.venv/bin/optimum-cli", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/macaw/sattwik/hello_clipseg/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/commands/optimum_cli.py", line 163, in main
    service.run()
  File "/home/macaw/sattwik/hello_clipseg/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/commands/export/onnx.py", line 265, in run
    main_export(
  File "/home/macaw/sattwik/hello_clipseg/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/onnx/__main__.py", line 280, in main_export
    model = TasksManager.get_model_from_task(
  File "/home/macaw/sattwik/hello_clipseg/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/tasks.py", line 1918, in get_model_from_task
    model_class = TasksManager.get_model_class_for_task(
  File "/home/macaw/sattwik/hello_clipseg/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/optimum/exporters/tasks.py", line 1378, in get_model_class_for_task
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Unrecognized configuration classes ('AutoModelForImageSegmentation', 'AutoModelForSemanticSegmentation') do not match with the model type clipseg and task image-segmentation.


Debugging
This error is probably because the CLIPSeg model uses a custom loader CLIPSegForImageSegmentation and the AutoModelFor... classes do not support this. I am new to HuggingFace and don't know whether this is causing the problem or something else.
What I tried
optimum-cli export onnx --model CIDAS/clipseg-rd16 ./models/clipsed-rd16

Expected
Something like the following but for CIDAS/clipseg-rd16.
Validating ONNX model distilbert_base_uncased_squad_onnx/model.onnx...
    -[✓] ONNX model output names match reference model (start_logits, end_logits)
    - Validating ONNX Model output "start_logits":
        -[✓] (2, 16) matches (2, 16)
        -[✓] all values close (atol: 0.0001)
    - Validating ONNX Model output "end_logits":
        -[✓] (2, 16) matches (2, 16)
        -[✓] all values close (atol: 0.0001)
The ONNX export succeeded and the exported model was saved at: distilbert_base_uncased_squad_onnx

This output is taken from the HuggingFace Optimum ONNX Documentation

Looks like this model is not supported: https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/auto/modeling_auto.py#L652

Please read Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers? - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.
